# How to apply condition in a max() function

Tags: r, max

I am new to R, I have diamonds data and I am trying to fetch the min and max price value for all the types of clarities(8 types) in data.
For that i have to make a function in which i can pass the condition which says :

```
where clarity == Clarity_type
```

do we see any solution here or any other approach?

Comment: min and max of what?

Comment: With `?tapply`?

Comment: @mtoto i meant price value

Comment: `max(diamonds$price[diamonds$clarity == "SI2"])`

Comment: No need for that, use `aggregate(diamonds$price, list(diamonds$clarity), function(x) c(min(x), max(x)))`.

Comment: `aggregate(price ~ clarity, diamonds, "range")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(diamonds$price, list(diamonds$clarity), function(x) c(min(x), max(x)))

  Group.1   x.1   x.2
1      I1   345 18531
2     SI2   326 18804
3     SI1   326 18818
4     VS2   334 18823
5     VS1   327 18795
6    VVS2   336 18768
7    VVS1   336 18777
8      IF   369 18806
```

---

Or better yet, as @docendodiscimus suggested, use the `range` function:

```
aggregate(diamonds$price, list(diamonds$clarity), range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try in the following way:

```
min(diamonds[diamonds$clarity=="I1",]$price)
max(diamonds[diamonds$clarity=="I1",]$price)
```

In this case you are looking for the max and the min price relative to the clarity type "I1", change that paramter with the clarity type you want and you're done.

Is this helpful?

Comment: This would require 16 lines of almost identical code .. pretty redundant, no?

Comment: Completely agree, I would look into the aggregate function.